# Cordova cli fetch error (can't add plugins or platforms)

Tags: node.js, cordova

When I tried to add a plugin or platform (or prepare the project), I'm always getting this:

```
Error: Failed to fetch plugin cordova-sqlite-storage@^2.0.4 via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
```

I tried to reinstall nodejs, uninstalled and reinstaled.
The same with cordova. I also tried to install a previous version of cordova.

Notes and environment:
- OS: Windows 10
- NPM packages are working

Comment: What's your node and npm versions?

Comment: @jcesarmobile NodeJS 6.11.0 NPM 3.10.10

Comment: can you try installing the plugins with `--nofetch` param?

Comment: @jcesarmobile done. Same error.